# Trouble extending event log messages

Tags: windows-xp, event-log

I'm trying to add some extended error codes to the event log but I get the following error.

> The description for Event ID ( 109 )
>   in Source ( PumpServer ) cannot be
>   found. The local computer may not have
>   the necessary registry information or
>   message DLL files to display messages
>   from a remote computer. You may be
>   able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to
>   retrieve this description; see Help
>   and Support for details. The following
>   information is part of the event: The
>   event log file is corrupt..

The message file looks like this and I added the one on the end:-

```
<---snip--->

MessageId=
SymbolicName=EVMSG_BADREQUEST
Language=English
The service received an unsupported request.
.

MessageId=
SymbolicName=EVMSG_DEBUG
Language=English
%1
.

MessageId=
SymbolicName=EVMSG_STOPPED
Language=English
The service was stopped.
.

MessageId=
SymbolicName=EVMSG_INVALIDLICENCE
Language=English
The service does not have a valid licence. Initialization failed.
.
```

It compiles fine.  The mc program is running over this file and producing a header file of the same name with my new message id showing.

```
//
// MessageId: EVMSG_INVALIDLICENCE
//
// MessageText:
//
// The service does not have a valid licence. Initialization failed.
//
#define EVMSG_INVALIDLICENCE             0x0000006DL
```

Any ideas why it's not finding my message?  All the others work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're linking with the resource file generated by the mc compiler.